# Realm is not updating existent objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using the Realm to save some objects and the user has the ability to reload them through a network function.

```
class Task: Object {

    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var price: Double = 0

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }

    func fillNew(json: JSON) {
        self.id = json["id"].stringValue
        self.name = json["prive"].doubleValue
    }
}
```

The network function get an array of json to build these objects. Once these new objects are created, I pass them through an add or update but when I fetch them again the fields have not changed.

```
func getPendingTasks(completion: (JSON?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let urlString = ".."
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString).responseJSON { response in
      let json = response.result.value != nil ? JSON(response.result.value!) : nil
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        completion(json, response.result.error)
      }
    }
}

func getTasks() {
    self.getPendingTasks() { json, error in
      if let error = error {
        return
      }

      let jsonTasks = json!["tasks"].arrayValue
      for jsonTask in jsonTasks {
        let task = Task()
        task.fillNew(jsonTask)
        self.tasks.append(task);
      }

      self.tasks = Task.sortGenericTasks(self.tasks)

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
          realm.add(self.tasks, update: true)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I'm currently using the latest version of realm, but can not pinpoint exactly what is happening or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you clarify what behavior you're seeing and how it differs from what you expect?